# How to make a click event in 'vscode.window.showInformationMessage'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a Information Box which contains a button, So when I click the button I need it to navigate to a web site in the button click event.

I was able to add a button inside Information box but now I don't have a clear understanding about how to make the button click event in 'vscode.window
        .showInformationMessage' since I'm new to typescript and extension development.So can anyone please guide me with this?

```
vscode.window
        .showInformationMessage("Click for more Info","Go to Help")
        .then(selection => {
        console.log(selection); 
        });
```

This prints 'Go to Help' in the debug console. this is just something I tried.But the expected result is when I click the Go to Help button it should navigate to specific url(ex: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hep). Can anyone guide me to get the expected output since I don't have any idea of how to get the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a "click event", simply check if the option has been selected in the callback:

```ts
let GoToHelp = 'Go to Help';
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Click for more Info', GoToHelp)
    .then(selection => {
      if (selection === GoToHelp) {
        vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse(
            'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hep'));
      }
    });
```

Comment: by any chance, do u know how to add a hyperlink in the message also? I observed a few extension has this feature.